# How to echo result of math expression AND save it to a variable in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need to get the following equation echoed to the command line, and also saved into a variable. So far I have failed to do either.

5^0.16

What I have tried.

```
echo 'e(l(5)*.16)' | bc -l
```

as well as

```
echo 'e(l(5)*.16)' | bc -l | read wcEXP
```

Comment: I'd store the equation in a variable, pipe that into `bc -l` and store the result (`result=$(echo "${equation}" | bc -l)`).  That'll give you both the equation and the result in variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```sh
wcExp=$(echo 'e(l(5)*.16)' | bc -l)
echo "$wcExp"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Bash, you can use `tee` to copy the output to standard error:

```
res=$(bc -l <<< 'e(l(5)*.16)' | tee /dev/stderr)
```

This will print the output of the `bc` command, and also store it in `res`:

```
$ res=$(bc -l <<< 'e(l(5)*.16)' | tee /dev/stderr)
1.29370483333398597850
$ declare -p res
declare -- res="1.29370483333398597850"
```